# linux fail2ban how to remove all banned ips

Tags: linux, centos7, fail2ban, firewalld

I am running CentOS 7 (firewalld not iptables) with the fail2ban v0.9.3.

How do I clear all bans without doing them one by one?

Comment: See [this](http://serverfault.com/a/336001) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fail2ban-client offers not such an option. May [this](http://blog.shanock.com/simple-script-to-clear-out-all-fail2ban-bans/) helps you (firewalld uses iptables).

Or you could try following (not supported):

**1. Get the Database location**

```
fail2ban-client get dbfile
```

**2. Stop the fail2ban service**

```
service fail2ban stop
```

**3. Modify the table 'bans'**

- `Sqliteman` can help you to modify the timestamp or delete entry's
- You could also try to rename the Database, maybe it will be recreated

**4. Start fail2ban Service**

```
service fail2ban start
```